# Why did I get a negative adjusted-$R^2$ in simple linear regression?

Tags: regression, linear-model, r-squared

I am running a simple linear regression $y\sim x$.

The $R^2$ is $0.002$, while the adjusted $R^2$ is $-0.001$.

I don't understand this. I had thought Adjusted $R^2$ can only be negative when we do multi-regression.

If there is only one variable, what is to be 'adjusted' in this case?

Does anyone know?

Comment: You have *two* variables: `x` and the implicit intercept.  See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coefficient_of_determination#Adjusted_R2, where $p=1$ counts `x` itself and the various "-1" scattered about the formula are for the intercept.

Answer (score 13):

Adjusted $R^2$ is:

$${R}_\text{adj}^{2}={1-(1-R^{2}){n-1 \over n-p-1}}$$

where $p$ is the number of predictors (not counting the intercept) and $n$ is the number of observations.

This will be less than $0$ when

$$\frac{p}{n-1}>R^2\,.$$

$R^2$ can be as low as $0$, so this may happen any time $p>0$. This means that it can indeed happen with $p=1$.

Answer (score 5):

A way to conceptualize this is that an adjusted $R^2$ estimates the population $R^2$, so an unbiased estimator of a population $R^2$ of zero has to average zero, thus necessitating that some sample estimates must be below zero.