# $R^2$ can be negative, but can it be -100% or lower?

Tags: goodness-of-fit, r-squared

I saw an $R^2$ statistic being reported as $-115\%$. I thought $R^2$ must be between $[-1, 1]$ so can it be negative to beyond $-1$?

Comment: $R^2$ of what? A linear model  $\mathbf{y}=\mathbf{X\beta}$ can't even have $R^2 < 0$. For different models, $R^2$ is usually meaningless anyway.

Comment: A regular $R^2$ cannot be negative, an adjusted-$R^2$, however, can. But there would need to be something seriously wrong for it to be that low. Unless they scaled it to $[-1,1]$ for some reason, then the difference is not that big (relatively).

Comment: For a reason for a negative *adjusted* $R^2$ see https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/313143/why-did-i-get-a-negative-adjusted-r2-in-simple-linear-regression

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you have the *total sum of squares* for the variable being predicted $$\mathrm{TSS}=\sum_{i=1}^{n}\left(y_{i}-\bar{y}\right)^2$$ and the *residual sum of squares* from the predictions from your model $$\mathrm{RSS}=\sum_{i=1}^{n}\left(y_{i}^{\,}-\hat{y}_i\right)^2$$ then you might say $$R^2 = 1-\frac{\mathrm{RSS}}{\mathrm{TSS}}$$ which makes sense as the sample $r^2$ in simple linear regression on one variable (the square of Pearson's correlation coefficient).  You then might then decide to use this $R^2$ as a definition of a measure of goodness-of-fit for other models even if it ceases to be the square of anything special

If your new model is in a sense worse than just using the average as a predictor, then you could have $\mathrm{RSS}  \gt \mathrm{TSS}$ and so an apparent $R^2 \lt 0$

If the predicted values from your model are so bad that $\mathrm{RSS}  \gt 2\,\mathrm{TSS}$ then you could have an apparent $R^2 \lt -1$